# Where is size_t Defined?

Tags: c++, types, namespaces, size-t, global-namespace

So I know any header from the [C Compatability Headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers):

> Places in the global namespace each name that the corresponding cxxx header would have placed in the `std` namespace

I also know that these C headers were deprecated as of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), in favor of their compatibility "cxxx" counterparts.

Now, I believe that `size_t` is defined exclusively by the [Standard Defines Header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstddef). So I presume this technically means that the definition of `size_t` in the global namespace has been deprecated?

I've been using it for years as just `size_t` and I'd just like a confirmation before I move to using `std::size_t`.

Comment: `Now, I believe that size_t is defined exclusively by the Standard Defines Header` is not exactly correct, since many of the C compatibility library headers besides `cstddef` define it.

Comment: @François I'm not sure this is a duplicate. OP wants to know if `::size_t` is deprecated.

Comment: @YSC The duplicate does address that `::size_t` is not required to be define. I would reason that it addresses the part about deprecation because the standard can't deprecate something it doesn't define.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I presume this technically means that the definition of size_t in the global namespace has been deprecated?

#### Yes... but.

The Standard only mandates that `std::size_t` must be defined<sup>1</sup> by `<cstddef>`, it does not disallow an implementation to define `::size_t`<sup>2</sup>, but if the implementation does, the two definitions must match<sup>3</sup>.

As a conclusion, you should use `std::size_t` and should neither rely on `::size_t` to be defined nor define it.

The following are UB:

```
// DON'T
using size_t = std::size_t;        // UB
using size_t = decltype(sizeof 1); // UB
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> [`[cstddef.syn]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstddef.syn)

> ```
> namespace std {
>     using ptrdiff_­t = see below;
>     using size_­t = see below;
>     using max_­align_­t = see below;
>     using nullptr_­t = decltype(nullptr);
> ```
>
> [...]
> The contents and meaning of the header `<cstddef>` are the same as the C standard library header `<stddef.h>`, except that it does not declare the type `wchar_­t`, that it also declares the type `byte` and its associated operations (`[support.types.byteops]`), and as noted in `[support.types.nullptr]` and `[support.types.layout]`.

<sup>2)</sup>[`[extern.types]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/reserved.names#extern.types-1)

> For each type `T` from the C standard library (These types are [...] `size_­t`,[...].), the types ​`::​T` and `std​::​T` are reserved to the implementation[.]

<sup>3)</sup>[`[extern.types]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/reserved.names#extern.types-1)

> [...] when defined, `​::​T` shall be identical to `std​::​T`.

Answer (score 3):

C-style header names like `<stddef.h>` are deprecated. However, C++-style headers like `<cstddef>` are allowed to declare their names in global namespace and then redeclare the same names in namespace `std` through *using-declarations* (http://eel.is/c++draft/organization#headers-4). This approach to declaring standard names is not deprecated. And many implementations do exactly that, for which reason it is not unusual to see name `size_t` accessible as a name from global namespace. But this is not guaranteed. So, in portable C++ code that includes `<cstddef>` you should use `std::size_t` and never rely on `::size_t`'s availability.

Answer (score 1):

The standard says `[expr.sizeof]`:

> The result of `sizeof` and `sizeof...` is a constant of type `std​::​size_­t`. [ Note: `std​::​size_­t` is defined in the standard header `<cstddef>` ([cstddef.syn], [support.types.layout]). — end note ]

Comment: You have a similar answer in the duplicate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This answer is different because it does not add to `std::`.

Comment: `Based on the above, I do not see why you cannot do: using size_t = decltype(sizeof 1);` You can't do that (in global namespace). `::size_t` is a reserved name, so defining it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user2079303 not anymore.

Comment: @YSC since when? It's reserved [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/reserved.names#footnote-182). Does the draft differ from the published standard? `For each type T ... the types ​::​T and ... are reserved to the implementation ... These types are ... size_­t ...`

Comment: @user2079303 Retracted that claim, it does not seem to be too popular.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is size_t Defined?

`::size_t` is *guaranteed* to be defined in `<stddef.h>` and few other C standard library headers that are inherited by c++. It *may* be defined by the implementation whether anything is included or not, since it is reserved, but relying on such non guaranteed definition would not be wise.

> So I presume this technically means that the definition of size_t in the global namespace has been deprecated?

Indeed. More precisely, all standard headers that are guaranteed to define `::size_t` are now deprecated in C++17. Same applies to all other non-macro C library names such as `::FILE`.