# Which header to include for size_t

Tags: c++, header, include, size-t

According to [cpprefernece](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) `size_t`is defined in various headers, namely
cstddef , cstdio, cstdlib, cstring, ctime, cuchar and (since C++17) cwchar.

My question is why is there not a single definition of `size_t`?  Which header do I include, if I just want `size_t`?

Comment: You can also `using size_t = decltype(sizeof 0);`, but my *go to* is `#include <cstddef>` followed by `using std::size_t;`.

Comment: @Eljay just don't do that in global namespace.

Comment: @eerorika • should be okay to do in the global namespace.  As an experiment, even okay to do before includes.  Or multiple times.  Or multiple times in different ways, e.g., `using size_t = decltype(sizeof 0); typedef unsigned long size_t;` (depending on the platform) if they all match.

Comment: @Eljay Standard says that defining reserved names is UB.

Comment: @eerorika • then that'd be bad.  But is `::size_t` a reserved name?  Of course `std::size_t` is reserved, because `std` namespace.  And typedef'ing `::size_t` to anything other than what it ought to be will collide with almost any include file.  I saw your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51500886/4641116

Comment: @Eljay It's reserved whether it's defined or not. Rule: `For each type T from the C standard library, the types ​::​T and std​::​T are reserved to the implementation and, when defined, ​::​T shall be identical to std​::​T.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why is there not a single definition of size_t?

There is a single definition for `std::size_t`. It's just defined in multiple headers since those headers themselves use that definition.

> Which header do I include, if I just want size_t?

Any of the ones that are specified to define it.

My choice is typically, `<cstddef>` because it is very small and has other definitions that I'm likely to need such as `std::byte`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally any standard library header may introduce any of the other header's declarations into the `std` namespace, but the declarations will always refer to the same entity and there won't be any one-definition-rule violation or anything like that. The headers listed on cppreference are just the ones for which a guarantee is made that they introduce `std::size_t`.

`<cstddef>` is probably the most minimal out of the headers and will also be available in a freestanding environment.

Note however, that none of the listed headers is guaranteed to introduce `size_t` into the global namespace scope. If you require this, you need to include one of the C versions of the headers, e.g. `#include<stddef.h>`.